# How to use local fonts in a create-react-app that's served by spring boot?

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, create-react-app

I am developing webapp with spring boot in the backend and react in the frontend (i use create-react-app to be specific). Now i thought it would be the easiest solution to have the frontend app served by spring whenever a root-level request comes in or even a request for any route thats not occupied by my backend API.

To integrate local fonts, i declare the font in `index.css` of my frontend:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TheFont';
    src: local('TheFont'), url(./fonts/TheFont/TheFont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

The font file is (in my project) located at `src/fonts`. Running it on the development server (`npm start`) everything works fine. But when i build the app and copy it to `resources/static/` in my spring boot backend, the fonts are not displayed while everything else works as expected.

The most confusing thing about this is that when i search the source of the website in my browser and follow the link to the rendered css and then the url to the font file (which looks like `../../static/media/TheFont.9f30b69a.ttf`) and request for that file directly via `localhost:8080/static/media/TheFont.9f30b69a.ttf`, i get the font file!
The path to the rendered css file is `static/css/main.767343db.css`, so the relative path to the font should be OK.

BTW i set `"homepage" : "."` in the `package.json` of the react app to get asset paths relative to the `index.html` file (as recommended in the many posts and examples i read).

What am i doing wrong? Could this be caused by the fact that i serve the frontend with the spring boot backend app?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is getting old now and was not answered at the time. It has 440 views, so it seems like many people are having similar problems. I solved this problem back in the days and want to let you know how, so everyone stranding here gets some insight:

**1) index.css**
I kept using the `index.css` as described in the question, so the font face definitions and paths to the font files look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TheFont';
    src: local('TheFont'), url(./fonts/TheFont/TheFont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

**2) package.json**
Then, in the `package.json`, i just didn't use the `homepage` property at all. The dev server ignores it anyway and later, when i needed a different path for my app in production, i set the `homepage` property to `/mypath/` without playing around with the `.` to get relative paths or something, it just worked without it.

**3) Spring static resources**
I just copied the build of my React app to `src/main/resources/static` of my Spring project, so the path to the `index.html` was `src/main/resources/static/index.html` and the fonts ended up in `src/main/resources/static/static/media/TheFont.ttf` (two `static` folders because one by Spring and the other is part of the Client's build structure).

BTW step 3) can nicely be automated with the Maven copy resources plugin - surely there's something similar for Gradle, too.

I hope this helps some of you who face this problem, too.